# ReactiveList updates doesn't seem to marshal correctly the first time in a UITableView

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, reactiveui

I have a problem with refreshing a UITableView correctly, at least the first time of ViewWillAppear and sometimes (rarely) might even hang the app. When I navigate away from the  UIViewController with changing tab item and navigate back, everything starts working perfectly for the entire lifecycle..

Having a ReactiveTableViewSource like below.

```
public class ATableViewSource : ReactiveTableViewSourceBase<IAViewModel>
{
    WeakReference<AListViewController> _weakContainer;
    Lazy<AListViewController> _lazyContainerViewController;

    AListViewController Container => _lazyContainerViewController.Value;

    public ATableViewSource(AListViewController container,
                            UITableView tableView,
                            IReactiveNotifyCollectionChanged<IAViewModel> collection)
        : base(tableView, collection,
                ATableViewCell.Key,
                ATableViewCell.Height,
                ATableViewCell.Height)
    {
        _weakContainer = new WeakReference<AListViewController>(container);
        tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(ATableViewCell.Nib, ATableViewCell.Key);

        _lazyContainerViewController = new Lazy<AListViewController>(() =>
        {
            AListViewController _container;
            _weakContainer.TryGetTarget(out _container);
            return _container;
        });
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        base.RowSelected(tableView, indexPath);

        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, false);
        var item = ItemAt(indexPath) as IAViewModel;
        if (item.IsNotNull())
        {
            AViewController viewController = new AViewController(item);
          Container.NavigationController.PushViewController(viewController, true);
        }
    }
}
```

In AListViewController.ViewDidLoad I have this setup.

```
ATableViewSource _viewSource;

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    TableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
    TableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 350.0f;
    TableView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(8.0f, 0.0f, 8.0f, 0.0f);

    _viewSource = new ATableViewSource(this, TableView, ViewModel.TheReactiveList);
    TableView.Source = _viewSource;
}
```

And in ViewWillAppear I always refresh the data (ViewModel.TheReactiveList).

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    ViewModel.RefreshTheReactiveList();
}
```

The AViewModel setup.

```
public class TheListViewModel : SchedulersViewModelBase, ITheListViewModel
{
    public ReactiveList<IAViewModel> TheReactiveList { get; } = new ReactiveList<IAViewModel> { ChangeTrackingEnabled = true };

    protected readonly IDataService DataService;

    public TheListViewModel(IScheduler mainScheduler,
                            IScheduler taskPoolScheduler,
                            IDataService dataService)
            : base(mainScheduler, taskPoolScheduler)
    {
        DataService = dataService;
    }

    public void RefreshTheReactiveList()
    {
        DataService.RefreshData()
                    .SubscribeOn(MainScheduler)
                    .ObserveOn(MainScheduler)
                    .Subscribe(ClearDataAndAddRange,
                                ex => AppObservables.Errors.OnNext(ex))
                    .DisposeWith(Disposables);
    }

    void ClearDataAndAddRange(IEnumerable<IAViewModel> data)
    {
        using (TheReactiveList.SuppressChangeNotifications())
        {
            TheReactiveList.Clear();
            TheReactiveList.AddRange(data);
        }
    }
}
```

I have to mention in this use case I have a parent UIViewController with two child controllers each with the same setup (UITableView, ReactiveTableViewSource, ViewModel.ReactiveList) and Hidden state is controlled for their UIView containers, but I noticed similar effects to UIViewController with one UITableView taking up to 3 seconds to show the results in the UITableView.

For your reference I am posting the `ReactiveTableViewSourceBase<TViewModel>` below, I have found this long time ago on the internet, so it might be suspicious. Changing the base class to a `ReactiveTableViewSource<TViewModel>` doesn't really make any difference though.

```
public abstract class ReactiveTableViewSourceBase<TViewModel> : ReactiveTableViewSource<TViewModel>, IInformsEnd
{
    private readonly Subject<Unit> _requestMoreSubject = new Subject<Unit>();
    private readonly Subject<CGPoint> _scrollSubject = new Subject<CGPoint>();

    public IObservable<CGPoint> DidScroll
    {
        get { return _scrollSubject.AsObservable(); }
    }

    public IObservable<Unit> RequestMore
    {
        get { return _requestMoreSubject; }
    }

    public override void Scrolled(UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        _scrollSubject.OnNext(scrollView.ContentOffset);
    }

    ~ReactiveTableViewSourceBase()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Destorying " + GetType().Name);
    }

    protected ReactiveTableViewSourceBase(UITableView tableView, nfloat height, nfloat? heightHint = null)
            : base(tableView)
    {
        tableView.RowHeight = height;
        tableView.EstimatedRowHeight = heightHint ?? tableView.EstimatedRowHeight;
    }

    protected ReactiveTableViewSourceBase(UITableView tableView, IReactiveNotifyCollectionChanged<TViewModel> collection,
            Foundation.NSString cellKey, nfloat height, nfloat? heightHint = null, Action<UITableViewCell> initializeCellAction = null)
            : base(tableView, collection, cellKey, (float)height, initializeCellAction)
    {
        tableView.RowHeight = height;
        tableView.EstimatedRowHeight = heightHint ?? tableView.EstimatedRowHeight;
    }

    public override void WillDisplay(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Section == (NumberOfSections(tableView) - 1) &&
            indexPath.Row == (RowsInSection(tableView, indexPath.Section) - 1))
        {
            // We need to skip an event loop to stay out of trouble
            BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => _requestMoreSubject.OnNext(Unit.Default));
        }
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var item = ItemAt(indexPath) as ICanGoToViewModel;
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.GoToCommand.Execute();
        }

        base.RowSelected(tableView, indexPath);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _requestMoreSubject.Dispose();
        _scrollSubject.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

public interface IInformsEnd
{
    IObservable<Unit> RequestMore { get; }
}
```